# "isn't numeric" warning from perl

Tags: perl

Perl keeps telling me that '11' from my input file is not numeric. Last time I checked 11 was a number, so I'm a bit confused what the problem is here and hence where to start looking.

Interestingly, it's line 1 of my input file causing the problem, the numbers on lines 2 onwards are interpreted correctly.

`Argument "11" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at ./extract.pl line 200, <INPUTFILE> line 1.`

Line 200 is

```
if ($_data[0] == $_ch && !exists $_ch_sn{$_data[1]}) { $_ch_sn{$_data[1]} = undef; }
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Show us `extract.pl`, at least line 200, and some sample input.

Comment: Can you check `length` of this argument?

Comment: line 200 (and the rest of the loop~) is:`if ($_data[0] == $_ch && !exists $_ch_sn{$_data[1]}) {
            $_ch_sn{$_data[1]} = undef;
        }`

Comment: I have a work around for now that is just to add a row to the top of my inputfile that I'm happy for perl to skip over when it reaches this problem. Everything works fine for the 2nd row (that was the 1st) in this case.

Comment: @epxlp Does your file have a BOM?

Comment: @Biffen `file` tells me this: `list.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text` so I assume no BOM. But I did think it had to be something like that.

Comment: @epxlp What does a hexdump of the first few bytes look like? (`head -c10 <file> | hexdump`)

Comment: @Biffen - thanks, I think you are onto something, a `setlocal bomb?` in Vi did indeed detect a bomb, so just removed and rerunning the perl script now. I think this should fix it, but will update when it's finished running! The `hexdump` option for detecting this looks useful too. Thanks!

Comment: In mysterious circumstances like these you should *always* check the contents of your data using `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; $Data::Dumper::Terse = 1; print Dumper $data[0];`. That would have shown the spurious character at the start of the string. BOM shares a code point with `ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE` which (intentionally) has no visible effect on text when it is displayed normally

Answer (score 4):

The error was caused by a BOM in my inputfile. Using `setlocal nobomb` in [Vi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the source doesn't actually contain `11` (e.g. maybe it contains a character that resembles a one but isn't), but I suspect the warning message is incorrectly identifying the expression that's non-numeric<sup>[1]</sup>.

That fact that nothing remotely resembling `11` appears on that line appears to support that<sup>[2]</sup>.

So just pretend you obtained the following warning:

```
Argument isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at ./extract.pl line 200, <INPUTFILE> line 1.
```

This means that `$_data[0]` or `$_ch` is a non-numeric string<sup>[2]</sup>.

- If both should be numbers, determine which one isn't, possibly using the following code:

  ```
  use Data::Dumper; { local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; warn(Dumper($_data[0], $_ch)); }
  ```

  Once you determine which variable is wrong, debug to find out why it is that way.
- If they could be legitimately be non-numeric, add appropriate checks to handle that situation.

---

1. For performance reasons, that part of the error message is deduced from the compiled code, a complicated and unreliable process.
2. I'm assuming the `if` has no `elsif` clause. Warnings from an `elsif` condition can appear to be from an `if` statement.